# Reading data in CSS

Tags: css, plotly-dash

I am building a `python` `plotly` `dash` webapp. I am using colors and fonts to style it, and I'd like these colors to be easily changeable. For now I need to declare them both in my `python` and `css` codes, as I used `plotly` for the graphs and `css` for the styling of some elements. Is there a wy to declare them in a single place, so that I dont have to change colors and fonts at several places. I am thinking something like a `json` file, which I can easily parse in `python` but dont know how to parse in `css`.

For now:

`Python` code:

```
color1 = "rgb(0, 63, 114)"
color2 = "rgb(0, 97, 152)"
font = "SourceSansProRegular"
```

`CSS` code:

```
:root {
    --dark-blue: rgb(0, 63, 114);
    --light-blue: rgb(0, 97, 152);
    --font: "SourceSansProRegular";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write pre-run python script that will create the CSS code from the JSON.

Another idea is to write another parser in JS that will parse the conf file and set values with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing another idea that I got from elsewhere: use the `tinycss` library of `python` to parse the CSS file with Python, making the CSS file the one source of truth